# XSLT sort node by employeeNumber, year, month, day, hour, minutes, seconds

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0

I have an XML and would like to :

- sort on employeeNumber, and for each bookingtime by year, month, day ascending.

Example :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <entry>
        <employeeName>Bob the Builder</employeeName>
        <employeeNumber>00290035</employeeNumber>
        <requestCode>g</requestCode>
        <bookingtime>
            <year>2019</year>
            <month>3</month>
            <day>18</day>
            <hours>14</hours>
            <minutes>52</minutes>
            <seconds>0</seconds>
        </bookingtime>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <employeeName>Bob the Builder</employeeName>
        <employeeNumber>00290035</employeeNumber>
        <requestCode>c</requestCode>
        <bookingtime>
            <year>2019</year>
            <month>3</month>
            <day>18</day>
            <hours>14</hours>
            <minutes>22</minutes>
            <seconds>0</seconds>
        </bookingtime>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <employeeName>Mike Zeh</employeeName>
        <employeeNumber>00200060</employeeNumber>
        <requestCode>c</requestCode>
        <bookingtime>
            <year>2019</year>
            <month>3</month>
            <day>17</day>
            <hours>10</hours>
            <minutes>15</minutes>
            <seconds>0</seconds>
        </bookingtime>
    </entry>
</root>
```

Can anyone help me do this properly? The XSLT version used can be any, no specific version required.

I made a small fiddle (https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ej9EGce), the sorting on employeeNumber works, year / month etc fails.

Comment: Do you want to sort the `entry` elements by the `empoyeeNumer`? Or also group them? If you only want to sort them, what is the sorting of `bookingtime` by the `year`/`month`/`day` components supposed to achieve, as each `entry` in the sample data seems to only have one `bookingtime` element? And in general, show us your attempt to sort, any tutorial on XSLT for sure has some use of `xsl:sort` with `xsl:for-each`/`xsl:apply-templates`/`xsl:perform-sort` so show an attempt.

Comment: I added a link to a Fiddle I created. No grouping required, entries sorted on employeenumber, next sorted by bookingtime (year/month/day/hours/ascending) ascending.

Comment: Consider to show the post in the question as well. So what is the result you want? Still not clear to me whether you want to simply sort the `entry` elements by all those sort keys (then simply add more `<xsl:sort select="bookingtime/year" order="ascending"/><xsl:sort select="bookingtime/month" order="ascending"/>...` where you do the `xsl:sort select="employeeNumber"`) or expect to have multiple `bookingtime` elements inside of an `entry` that need to be sorted as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This stylesheet

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="root">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="entry">
                <xsl:sort select="employeeNumber" data-type="number"/>
                <xsl:sort select="bookingtime/year" data-type="number"/>
                <xsl:sort select="bookingtime/month" data-type="number"/>
                <xsl:sort select="bookingtime/day" data-type="number"/>
                <xsl:sort select="bookingtime/hours" data-type="number"/>
                <xsl:sort select="bookingtime/minutes" data-type="number"/>
                <xsl:sort select="bookingtime/seconds" data-type="number"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With your input

```
<root>
    <entry>
        <employeeName>Bob the Builder</employeeName>
        <employeeNumber>00290035</employeeNumber>
        <requestCode>g</requestCode>
        <bookingtime>
            <year>2019</year>
            <month>3</month>
            <day>18</day>
            <hours>14</hours>
            <minutes>52</minutes>
            <seconds>0</seconds>
        </bookingtime>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <employeeName>Bob the Builder</employeeName>
        <employeeNumber>00290035</employeeNumber>
        <requestCode>c</requestCode>
        <bookingtime>
            <year>2018</year>
            <month>3</month>
            <day>18</day>
            <hours>14</hours>
            <minutes>22</minutes>
            <seconds>0</seconds>
        </bookingtime>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <employeeName>Mike Zeh</employeeName>
        <employeeNumber>00200060</employeeNumber>
        <requestCode>c</requestCode>
        <bookingtime>
            <year>2019</year>
            <month>3</month>
            <day>17</day>
            <hours>10</hours>
            <minutes>15</minutes>
            <seconds>0</seconds>
        </bookingtime>
    </entry>
</root>
```

Output:

```
<root>
   <entry>
      <employeeName>Mike Zeh</employeeName>
      <employeeNumber>00200060</employeeNumber>
      <requestCode>c</requestCode>
      <bookingtime>
         <year>2019</year>
         <month>3</month>
         <day>17</day>
         <hours>10</hours>
         <minutes>15</minutes>
         <seconds>0</seconds>
      </bookingtime>
   </entry>
   <entry>
      <employeeName>Bob the Builder</employeeName>
      <employeeNumber>00290035</employeeNumber>
      <requestCode>c</requestCode>
      <bookingtime>
         <year>2018</year>
         <month>3</month>
         <day>18</day>
         <hours>14</hours>
         <minutes>22</minutes>
         <seconds>0</seconds>
      </bookingtime>
   </entry>
   <entry>
      <employeeName>Bob the Builder</employeeName>
      <employeeNumber>00290035</employeeNumber>
      <requestCode>g</requestCode>
      <bookingtime>
         <year>2019</year>
         <month>3</month>
         <day>18</day>
         <hours>14</hours>
         <minutes>52</minutes>
         <seconds>0</seconds>
      </bookingtime>
   </entry>
</root>
```

Do note: if your are sorting `entry` elements you can use any relative path with each `entry` as context for the `select` attribute of `xsl:sort` instruction. This is **sorting** (output every `entry`) different from grouping (output disctint `entry` and compute some aggregation)

Comment: You should use `data-type="number"` for sorting the numeric fields, otherwise 11 will sort before 3.

Answer (score 1):

I like Aljandro's answer, but in case somebody **insists** on using a higher version of XSLT and treating the values really as those of *year*, *month*, *day-of-month*, *hours*, *minutes* and *seconds*, then something like below can be used,

This transformation may look a little bit more complex, but it treats the children of <bookingtime> as values of these typed objects and will throw an error if an invalid component value is encountered -- such as *Feb* 30th, *month*: 13, *hour*: 25, or *minute*/*second* 61

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="root">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="entry">
                <xsl:sort select="employeeNumber" data-type="number"/>
                <xsl:sort select=
                "xs:dateTime(concat(
                                 string-join(
                                  (
                                      format-number(bookingtime/year, '0000'),
                                      format-number(bookingtime/month, '00'),
                                      format-number(bookingtime/day, '00')
                                  ), '-'
                                             ),
                                 'T',
                                 string-join(
                                  (
                                      format-number(bookingtime/hours, '00'),
                                      format-number(bookingtime/minutes, '00'),
                                      format-number(bookingtime/seconds, '00')
                                  ), ':'
                                            )
                                   )
                             )"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided source xml document**:

```
<root>
    <entry>
        <employeeName>Bob the Builder</employeeName>
        <employeeNumber>00290035</employeeNumber>
        <requestCode>g</requestCode>
        <bookingtime>
            <year>2019</year>
            <month>3</month>
            <day>18</day>
            <hours>14</hours>
            <minutes>52</minutes>
            <seconds>0</seconds>
        </bookingtime>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <employeeName>Bob the Builder</employeeName>
        <employeeNumber>00290035</employeeNumber>
        <requestCode>c</requestCode>
        <bookingtime>
            <year>2018</year>
            <month>3</month>
            <day>18</day>
            <hours>14</hours>
            <minutes>22</minutes>
            <seconds>0</seconds>
        </bookingtime>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <employeeName>Mike Zeh</employeeName>
        <employeeNumber>00200060</employeeNumber>
        <requestCode>c</requestCode>
        <bookingtime>
            <year>2019</year>
            <month>3</month>
            <day>17</day>
            <hours>10</hours>
            <minutes>15</minutes>
            <seconds>0</seconds>
        </bookingtime>
    </entry>
</root>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<root>
   <entry>
        <employeeName>Mike Zeh</employeeName>
        <employeeNumber>00200060</employeeNumber>
        <requestCode>c</requestCode>
        <bookingtime>
            <year>2019</year>
            <month>3</month>
            <day>17</day>
            <hours>10</hours>
            <minutes>15</minutes>
            <seconds>0</seconds>
        </bookingtime>
    </entry>
   <entry>
        <employeeName>Bob the Builder</employeeName>
        <employeeNumber>00290035</employeeNumber>
        <requestCode>c</requestCode>
        <bookingtime>
            <year>2018</year>
            <month>3</month>
            <day>18</day>
            <hours>14</hours>
            <minutes>22</minutes>
            <seconds>0</seconds>
        </bookingtime>
    </entry>
   <entry>
        <employeeName>Bob the Builder</employeeName>
        <employeeNumber>00290035</employeeNumber>
        <requestCode>g</requestCode>
        <bookingtime>
            <year>2019</year>
            <month>3</month>
            <day>18</day>
            <hours>14</hours>
            <minutes>52</minutes>
            <seconds>0</seconds>
        </bookingtime>
    </entry>
</root>
```